# document.body.scrollHeight not working with Ipad in swift

Tags: swift

I tried to get content size of WKWebView by below code but It only work with the Iphone. with the Ipad It didn't work. Can you resolve help me this issue? Thanks.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
    if complete != nil {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
           //
        })
    }

    })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with this code, it return extract content size of WKWebView:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: {[weak self] (complete, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                let heightWebView = height as? CGFloat ?? 0
                print("\(heightWebView)----------------")
            })
        }
    })
```